# File uploaded using postman shows undefined in request body

Tags: postman, multipartform-data

I am trying to create a multipart/form-data request in postman as below

[image]

However, while sending this request, I could see postman showing undefined for the fileToUpload

[image]

Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: tahts a bug in the new app , the file gets uploaded correctly

Comment: Check this. https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/installation/settings/#working-directory

Answer (score 2):

In my case it is showing undefined when I'm attaching a file to the multipart but the file is sent successfully.

I checked it because I used a mock endpoint to inspect the request payload being sent.

You can use any similar tool to check it:

- [HttpToolkit](https://httptoolkit.tech/) (what I used)
- [Requestbin](https://requestbin.com/)
- [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Or any network sniffer.